# How to access differently nested string array swift 5

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

and good job , well basically i have array like this :

```
let imageArray = [ ["image0"] , ["image11","image12"] , ["image2"], ["image31","image32","image33"] ]
```

In this point i want to put for example first item of each nested array into a new array like this :

```
var newArray = ["image0","image11","image2","image31"]
```

And also i want to have a condition for example if "image31" clicked we have a new page that show ervery images of  that first array show us, like ["image31", "image32", "image33"]

So could you tell any idea how can implement like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
let res = imageArray.map { $0.first! }
```

When clicked use the index to access other elements , say from above index 3 image is clicked then use

```
let resImages = imageArray[clickedIndex]
```

**Edit:**

```
let arr = ["images/product/2021-05-02T09-47-17.699Z-download (2).jpg"]

let res = arr.map { $0[$0.range(of: "images/product/")!.upperBound...] }
        
print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks for attention, i updated my question , in second part , i want this if user clicked each item of newArray then in new page show each image array  that related to clicked image

Comment: set imageView tag = index of the image you set it to from above `res` then use that tag of the clicked imageView to get `resImages` from above

Comment: Ok i will try that , again thanks and good luck

Comment: I have a problem with that, when I use your solution , I mean first line ,  and my string is "images/product/2021-05-02T09-47-17.699Z-download (2).jpg" its just return to me first character of this string not all of the string, what do I do?

Comment: `imageArray` should be an array of a string array

Comment: I know that imageArray is array of string but again I got "i"

Comment: what u need to get ?

Comment: for example my array is ["images/product/2021-05-02T09-47-17.699Z-download (2).jpg"] and when I use your let res = imageArray.map { $0.first! } I just got "i" first character of string. and also my app crash

Comment: Do u need `2021-05-02T09-47-17.699Z-download (2).jpg`  ?

Answer (score 1):

Using simple data structures (like arrays) to model complex data is rarely the best approach.

In this case I would create a struct `ImageList` and then create an array of this struct

```
struct ImageList {
   let images: [String]
   var firstImage: String? {
       return self.images.first
   }
}
```

You can use `map` to create the array from your current source, if required

```
   imageListArray = imageArray.map { ImageList(images:$0) }
```

Now you can have an index that is associated with an `ImageList` struct - `imageListArray[i].firstImage!` is the value you want for your list and `iageListArray[i].images` is the array you want for your second requirement.

Comment: hi brother could you say what is imageListArray? because its unknown for me

Comment: It would be `var imageListArray[ImageList]` - you haven't said what you are doing with the array, but this would be the array for your tableview or lost view or whatever.